# charts.js displays only first x and y value from a json api response

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I am trying to render a chart with charts.js with a json api but the rendered chart displays only the first x and y values from the json

[image]

**the json is fetched using xmlhttp**

```
var url = "https://syed1ahmed.github.io/stage-gear/api.json";
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        date = data.data.map(function (elem) {
            return elem.x;
        })

        volume = data.data.map(function (elem) {
            return elem.y;
        })
        
        const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: date,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'daily volume in USD',
                    data: volume,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    y: {

                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**json api link**
https://syed1ahmed.github.io/stage-gear/api.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `Chart.js` does not recognize the thousands separators (`,`) in your values. You can get around your problem by simply remove them using [`replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) as follows:

```
volume = data.data.map(function (elem) {
  return elem.y.replaceAll(',', '');
});
```

Please take a look at your amended code (no `HTTP` call) and see how it works.

```js
var data = {
  "data": [{
      "x": "Jun 01, 2018",
      "y": "52.78124425595927"
    },
    {
      "x": "Jul 01, 2018",
      "y": "5,418.613108428228"
    },
    {
      "x": "Aug 01, 2018",
      "y": "203,981.26814003725"
    },
    {
      "x": "Sep 01, 2018",
      "y": "41,855.35334764546"
    },
    {
      "x": "Oct 01, 2018",
      "y": "47,121.06598405195"
    },
    {
      "x": "Nov 01, 2018",
      "y": "68,219.78481479896"
    },
    {
      "x": "Dec 01, 2018",
      "y": "106,208.66125578032"
    },
    {
      "x": "Jan 01, 2019",
      "y": "261,214.899791384"
    },
    {
      "x": "Feb 01, 2019",
      "y": "331,730.6884339796"
    },
    {
      "x": "Mar 01, 2019",
      "y": "649,319.4385028543"
    },
    {
      "x": "Apr 01, 2019",
      "y": "679,321.6099113098"
    },
    {
      "x": "May 01, 2019",
      "y": "698,144.0531540666"
    },
    {
      "x": "Jun 01, 2019",
      "y": "484,173.3966476037"
    },
    {
      "x": "Jul 01, 2019",
      "y": "531,748.0974990415"
    },
    {
      "x": "Aug 01, 2019",
      "y": "494,265.2626726319"
    },
    {
      "x": "Sep 01, 2019",
      "y": "715,725.4201179789"
    },
    {
      "x": "Oct 01, 2019",
      "y": "1,837,100.6108408063"
    },
    {
      "x": "Nov 01, 2019",
      "y": "850,018.0923909895"
    },
    {
      "x": "Dec 01, 2019",
      "y": "854,509.2031143928"
    },
    {
      "x": "Jan 01, 2020",
      "y": "1,007,118.1584876713"
    },
    {
      "x": "Feb 01, 2020",
      "y": "1,530,670.3881858303"
    },
    {
      "x": "Mar 01, 2020",
      "y": "1,100,377.6202637332"
    },
    {
      "x": "Apr 01, 2020",
      "y": "1,048,740.4987093885"
    },
    {
      "x": "May 01, 2020",
      "y": "1,066,146.957757765"
    },
    {
      "x": "Jun 01, 2020",
      "y": "917,965.8857672011"
    },
    {
      "x": "Jul 01, 2020",
      "y": "1,076,082.076370403"
    },
    {
      "x": "Aug 01, 2020",
      "y": "937,071.1236946463"
    },
    {
      "x": "Sep 01, 2020",
      "y": "2,747,539.4456087383"
    },
    {
      "x": "Oct 01, 2020",
      "y": "4,773,432.3952869885"
    },
    {
      "x": "Nov 01, 2020",
      "y": "4,483,383.749190311"
    },
    {
      "x": "Dec 01, 2020",
      "y": "3,568,749.2548671504"
    },
    {
      "x": "Jan 01, 2021",
      "y": "8,072,866.650029003"
    },
    {
      "x": "Feb 01, 2021",
      "y": "96,731,289.37183556"
    },
    {
      "x": "Mar 01, 2021",
      "y": "148,017,660.0724626"
    },
    {
      "x": "Apr 01, 2021",
      "y": "95,779,027.33114299"
    },
    {
      "x": "May 01, 2021",
      "y": "138,917,885.22552317"
    },
    {
      "x": "Jun 01, 2021",
      "y": "150,308,148.9535175"
    },
    {
      "x": "Jul 01, 2021",
      "y": "328,964,751.5721974"
    },
    {
      "x": "Aug 01, 2021",
      "y": "3,421,850,687.562206"
    },
    {
      "x": "Sep 01, 2021",
      "y": "2,991,073,935.3753285"
    },
    {
      "x": "Oct 01, 2021",
      "y": "2,548,526,282.894439"
    },
    {
      "x": "Nov 01, 2021",
      "y": "2,162,564,606.528579"
    },
    {
      "x": "Dec 01, 2021",
      "y": "2,559,484,013.292382"
    },
    {
      "x": "Jan 01, 2022",
      "y": "4,857,435,382.1052265"
    },
    {
      "x": "Feb 01, 2022",
      "y": "3,326,430,045.315286"
    },
    {
      "x": "Mar 01, 2022",
      "y": "2,483,354,859.0230055"
    },
    {
      "x": "Apr 01, 2022",
      "y": "3,487,751,260.8629684"
    },
    {
      "x": "May 01, 2022",
      "y": "2,596,397,753.7464023"
    },
    {
      "x": "Jun 01, 2022",
      "y": "695,420,425.3349748"
    },
    {
      "x": "Jul 01, 2022",
      "y": "528,641,117.64340025"
    },
    {
      "x": "Aug 01, 2022",
      "y": "502,093,181.84102654"
    },
    {
      "x": "Sep 01, 2022",
      "y": "38,051,752.44172493"
    }
  ]
};

const date = data.data.map(function(elem) {
  return elem.x;
});

const volume = data.data.map(function(elem) {
  return elem.y.replaceAll(',', '');
});

//console.log(date)

new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: date,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'daily volume in USD',
      data: volume,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```